# How to make Google line chart dynamic in MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

This is my current line chart. I need to make the number of line dynamic. (Standard,Latest,Earliest,Average) should be adjustable depending on the database records. My code is almost like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/).

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Month', 'Standard', 'Latest', 'Earliest', 'Average'],
            ['Original Documents', @Convert.ToDecimal(@Standard[0].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Latest[0].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Earliest[0].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Average[0].ToString())],
            ["Filing of Entries", @Convert.ToDecimal(@Standard[1].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Latest[1].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Earliest[1].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Average[1].ToString())],
            ["Assessment of Duties", @Convert.ToDecimal(@Standard[2].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Latest[2].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Earliest[2].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Average[2].ToString())],
            ["Payment of Duties", @Convert.ToDecimal(@Standard[3].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Latest[3].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Earliest[3].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Average[3].ToString())],
            ["Releasing", @Convert.ToDecimal(@Standard[4].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Latest[4].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Earliest[4].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Average[4].ToString())],
            ["Gate Pass", @Convert.ToDecimal(@Standard[5].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Latest[5].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Earliest[5].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Average[5].ToString())],
            ["Delivery", @Convert.ToDecimal(@Standard[6].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Latest[6].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Earliest[6].ToString()), @Convert.ToDecimal(@Average[6].ToString())]
        ]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not change your function to accept a Json array like this:

```
function drawChart(jsonData) {
    var array = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
    var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'X-Axis Legend'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Y-Axis Legend'
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Note the row-per-x-position, column-per-line data format as [described in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format):

> Rows: Each row in the table represents a set of data points with the
>   same x-axis location.

Then you could send Json from your controller method a bit like this, with each new line and its data being added using some kind of loop or whatever (you can easily work out how to do this):

```
var data = new[] {  
    new[] {"Month", "Line1", "Line2", "Line3", "Line4"}, // add new lines, e.g. new[] {"Month", "Line1", "Line2", "Line3", "Line4", ...., ...., "LineN"},
    new object[] {"x-label1", 1, 2, 3, 4 }, // add new data points as above
    new object[] {"x-label2", 11, 12, 13, 14 },
    new object[] {"x-label3", 7, 6, 2, 17 },
    new object[] {"x-label3", 17, 19, 23, 9 },
    new object[] {"x-label3", 12, 4, 11, 18 }
};
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

This example returns the following Json:

```
[["Month","Line1","Line2","Line3","Line4"],["x-label1",1,2,3,4],["x-label2",11,12,13,14],["x-label3",7,6,2,17],["x-label3",17,19,23,9],["x-label3",12,4,11,18]]
```

Finally, [here is a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Dommer/dbn65bLz/) I knocked up which includes the above json data hard-coded and draws a graph.

**EDIT:** Here is some sample C# code to convert your line data from row into columnar format. It generates as many lines of data as you want. Obviously you'd read this data from elsewhere. In your case your original line data is currently stored in variables with names like `Standard`, `Latest`, etc. Change the value for `numberOfLines` and paste the resultant Json into the JSFiddle example to see:

```
var numberOfLines = 7; // Choose how many lines you want.
var xAxisHeadings = new object[] { "NOT USED", "Original Documents", "Filing of Entries", "Assessment of Duties", "Payment of Duties", "Releasing", "Gate Pass", "Delivery" };
var lines = new List<object[]>();
lines.Add(xAxisHeadings);

// Each line needs to be an array with the first value being the name of the line 
// (e.g. Standard, Latest, Earliest, Average in your case) and the rest
// being the actual values in order.
// In the following example, line n has values n, 2n, 3n, 4n, 5n, 6n, 7n
// e.g. line seven has the values 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49 
for (int i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++)
{
    lines.Add(new object[] { "L" + i, 1 * (i+1), 2 * (i+1), 3 * (i+1), 4 * (i+1), 5 * (i+1), 6 * (i+1), 7 * (i+1) });
}

var answer = new List<object>{};
for (int i=0; i<lines.Count; i++)
{
    var x = lines.Select(a => a[i]).ToArray();
    answer.Add(x);
}

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(answer);
```

This new example returns the following Json:

```
[["NOT USED","L0","L1","L2","L3","L4","L5","L6"],["Original Documents",1,2,3,4,5,6,7],["Filing of Entries",2,4,6,8,10,12,14],["Assessment of Duties",3,6,9,12,15,18,21],["Payment of Duties",4,8,12,16,20,24,28],["Releasing",5,10,15,20,25,30,35],["Gate Pass",6,12,18,24,30,36,42],["Delivery",7,14,21,28,35,42,49]]
```

Pasting this into the previous JSFiddle example gives us this [new JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dbn65bLz/2/).

Comment: can you explain it more. How do i call the json function?

Comment: I'm not sure what else to explain. Did you look at the JSFiddle example? If so then the only remaining problems are (1) to generate the Json somehow, probably in your ActionMethod since you're using MVC4. Then (2) to get the data into the right format. I've given some C# code doing that too.

Comment: the number of line is dynamic. your example has a total of 4 lines right? i need to make it dynamic it can be less or more than 4.

Comment: I have added some C# code to generate the line data dynamically and then to translate it into the columnar Json required.